# Center horizontal navigation menu

Tags: html, css, navigation, center

Struggling to center the nav bar in the middle of the browser... Tried a number of the things found through google but no luck as yet. Seems like it should be such an easy thing to do but its turned out to be a pain in the neck!

Heres the code.

```
<div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="home"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li class="detail"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                <li class="work"><a href="work.php">Work</a></li>
                <li class="contact"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

#nav {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;  }
#nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#nav li {
    float: left; }
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #069;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li:first-child a {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li a:hover {

color: #50B748;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not using floats but rather `display:inline-block` instead.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/9ELje/11/)

**CSS**

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#nav {
    //width: 100%; /* not required */
    //float: left; /* not required */
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    padding: 0;    
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;  }

#nav ul {
    width:100%;
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center; /* add this */
}
#nav li {
   //float: left;  /* remove */
    display: inline-block; /* add this */
}
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #069;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }

#nav li:first-child a {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc; }

#nav li a:hover {    
    color: #50B748;
}
```

**EDIT - added reset of `ul` padding/margin**

Comment: thanks, it is still slight offset to the right though, any ideas?

Comment: You have to reset the padding on the `ul` - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/9ELje/10/

Comment: there is no padding on the ul? by offset, i would say its to the right by about 30px

Comment: It's automatically added by the browser...so you have to reset it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `margin-top:50%;` to it

just like this:

```
#nav {


    width: 100%;
    float: left;
margin-top:50%;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;  }
#nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#nav li {
    float: left; }
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #069;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li:first-child a {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li a:hover {

color: #50B748;

}
```

Does this solve your problem?
Or didn't I understand your question ?

Comment: No...you didn't understand...not centered vertically, centered horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `text-align: center;` in you `#nav` style. And reset `UL` default margin It should be like this

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="home"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li class="detail"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                <li class="work"><a href="work.php">Work</a></li>
                <li class="contact"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;  }
#nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}
#nav li {
    float: left; }
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #069;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li:first-child a {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li a:hover {

color: #50B748;

}
```